# Чат-боты, запоминание последней темы

Tags: php, архитектура, искусственный-интеллект

Хоть здесь и не приветствуются вопросы-обсуждения, решил все-таки создать подобный. Как лучше сделать запоминание темы для чат-бота на PHP.

Пока такие мысли:
Попадается ключевое слово - добавляется тема, дальнейшие сообщения записываются к ней, и уже анализируются только они, как этакая память. Но как можно было бы в целом сделать лучше этот механизм?

Comment: регуляркой проверять?

Comment: Да уже проверяю, но вопрос в лучшей архитектуре :)